# What is the gradient of $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(x^2)^\top A(x^2)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, scalar-fields, hadamard-product

Let matrix $A$ be sparse and symmetric but not semidefinite. Since I would like to use projected gradient descent, I must find the gradient of $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(x^2)^\top A(x^2)$, where $x^2 = \operatorname{diag}(x)x$,
$$\operatorname{diag}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x_3 \end{pmatrix},$$ and $x \in \mathbb R^n$. How can I do it?

I know the cases where $x^2$ is replaced by $x$ but not this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let \begin{gather*}
f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^{\mathsf{T}}\mathcal{A}x \\
g(x)=\mathrm{diag}(x)x
\end{gather*}

You already know $$\mathcal{D}(f)(x)=x^{\mathsf{T}}\mathcal{A}$$  We can compute directly $$\mathcal{D}(g)(x)_{j,k}=\frac{\partial(x_j^2)}{\partial x_k}=2x_j\delta_{j,k}$$ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.  Thus $$\mathcal{D}(g)(x)=2\mathrm{diag}{(x)}$$

Finally, by the multivariate chain rule, $$\mathcal{D}(f\circ g)(x)=\mathcal{D}(f)(g(x))\mathcal{D}(g)(x)=2x^{\mathsf{T}}\mathrm{diag}(x)^{\mathsf{T}}\mathcal{A}\mathrm{diag}{(x)}$$

Comment: apparently i thought i could implicitly deal with the derivations of $x^2$ but thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "implicitly".  But there's a general principle here: if $f$ is a one-variable function that we extend "coordinatewise" to a function $F$ on vectors, then $\mathcal{D}(F)=\mathrm{diag}(f')$.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\h{\tfrac 12}
$The gradient can be calculated using the
Hadamard $(\odot)$ and
Frobenius $(:)$ products
$$\eqalign{
w &= x\odot x \quad\qiq {dw} = 2x\odot dx \\
\phi &= \h w^TAw \\
 &= \h A:ww^T \\
d\phi
 &= \h A:\LR{dw\;w^T+w\;dw^T} \\
 &= \h\LR{A+A^T}:\LR{\c{dw}\;w^T} \\
 &= Aw:\c{dw} \\
 &= Aw:\CLR{2x\odot dx} \\
 &= \LR{2x\odot Aw}:dx \\
\grad{\phi}{x} &= {2x\odot Aw} \\
}$$
These specialized products can be replaced by traces and diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= \trace{A^TBC} \;=\; AC^T:B \;=\; CA^T:B^T \\
X &= \Diag x \;\implies\; Xb = x\odot b \\
\grad{\phi}{x}
 &= {2XAXx} \\
}$$